# Magento 2 Docker Crontab and system upgrade

Tags: php, docker, magento2

I've got Magento 2 which I wrapped arround docker-compose. Following design patterns I am using one service for one task. So at this moment I have:

- mysql database
- redis for cache
- my magento with apache
- additionall service running cron - using the same image as magento but different entrypoint.

Cron is running properly, my tasks are visible and finishing correctly.

Here comes the quesion: does cron need access to magento files ?

When I try to enter `System -> Web Setup Wizard -> System Upgrade` I've got errors saying my cron is not working correctly. So my only option to upgrade Magento to new version is to do it by manually chaning files and rebuilding image ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your cron will need access to your Magento files, I am assuming there is a PHP script that gets ran by cron like many other frameworks.

What I have done previously is ran cron from the host container like this:

```
5 4 * * * docker exec -it magento exec php /var/www/cron.php
```

Comment: I do not see cron accessing files anywhere. I can see it doing only database tasks.  I do not want to manually start cron with every update / deployment - I want it to be started automatically every time